# read high frequency signal from serial port using matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to read a signal from seril port (sent with arduino). you can see in my code that I made some thing but not sufficient because the delay required to read one value is in ordre of 0.8s(delay between 'tic' an 'toc'.
this is my code in matlab if anyone has an advice.

```
%User Defined Properties 
serialPort = 'COM6';            % define COM port #

%Define Function Variables
time = 0;
data = 0;
count = 0;

%Open Serial COM Port
s = serial(serialPort,'BaudRate', 9600);
fopen(s);

tic
while (toc<=10) 

    dat = fscanf(s,'%f'); %Read Data from Serial as Float      
    count = count + 1;    
    time(count) = toc;    %Extract Elapsed Time
    data(count) = dat(1); %Extract 1st Data Element  
end


%Close Serial COM Port
fclose(s);
delete(s);
disp('Session Terminated...');
```

Think you all!

Comment: According to the docs, you need to use `read`: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serialport.read.html

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'serialport'.

Error in readasyn (line 1)
s = serialport('COM6', 'InputBufferSize', 3600);

Comment: As Ander said, use `read` for reading float, and for timing stick your acquisition in an event callback triggered when data arrive at the serial port, use the [`bytesavailablefcn`](https://mathworks.com/help/instrument/bytesavailablefcn.html),

Comment: I got this issue, maybe it does not work with my version of matlab

Comment: Could you clarify which version you have? As you said this is a new functionality, so you may have an older version

Comment: I have matlab 2018a.

Comment: Anyway, I used "fread". it works very well.